# Question on linear mappings in linear algebra

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations

In the textbook "Mathematics for Machine Learning," I came across a theorem that stated

> Finite-dimensional vector spaces $V$ and $W$ are isomorphic if and only if $\dim(V) = \dim(W)$.

The textbook then proceeds to explain that this theorem gives the

> ... justification to treat $\mathbb{R}^{m \times n}$ (the vector space of $m \times n$ matrices) and $\mathbb{R}^{mn}$ (the vector space of vectors of length $mn$) the same, as their dimensions are $mn$, and there exists a linear bijective mapping that transforms one into the other.

From what I understand of my learning of linear algebra, the dimension of the vector space of $m \times n$ matrices would be the number of its independent column vectors. I have never come across anyone calculating the dimensions of a matrix by the product of its rows and columns. I must be missing something. Can anyone help me out, please?

Comment: Use `\times` for the multiplication symbol, not `x`

Comment: You are confusing the columnspace of a particular matrix with the vector space of *all* $m\times n$ matrices, which are a vector space under matrix addition and scalar multiplication.

Comment: You are talking about the dimension of the range of **one** $m \times n$ matrix. They are talking about the collection of **all** $m \times n$ matrices as  a vector space whose dimesion turns out to be $mn$.

Answer (score 1):

In comments, people gave the proper reason. I would like to elaborate on that.

Let $A$ be $m \times n$ a matrix. So, $A$ looks like
\begin{equation}
\left( \begin{array}{ccc}
a_{11} & \cdots & a_{1n}\\
\vdots & \ddots & \vdots\\
a_{m1} & \cdots & a_{mn}
\end{array} \right)
\end{equation}

Now we consider the vector space $V$ of all $m \times n$ matrices. Now clearly we can define a linear transformation from $V \to \mathbb{R}^{mn}$ by
\begin{equation}
\left( \begin{array}{ccc}
a_{11} & \cdots & a_{1n}\\
\vdots & \ddots & \vdots\\
a_{m1} & \cdots & a_{mn}
\end{array} \right) \longmapsto 
(a_{11} \, \dots \,a_{mn})
\end{equation}

and it is easy to check that the map is an isomorphism.

Comment: So basically, we're treating matrices as vectors? Thanks for your answer by the way.

Comment: Yes! That's what we're doing.